# React Rich Text Editor - Clear state on ENTER

Tags: reactjs, rich-text-editor, enter, rte

I would like to clear the state of the React Rich Text Editor (https://github.com/sstur/react-rte) when pressing the enter-key.

My state looks like this:

```
state = {
    value: RichTextEditor.createEmptyValue()
}
```

The `RichTextEditor`component offers to provide the handleReturn prop. Thus, I have implemented the following `handleReturn` function:

```
handleReturn = () => {this.setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      value: RichTextEditor.createValueFromString("", "html")
    }));
}
```

When I trigger the handleReturn function from a button outside the RichTextEditor itself, it works perfectly and the state (and text input area) is properly cleared. However, when the same handleReturn is triggered from the enter-key it is not clearing the state; but I can see that the handleReturn function is correctly triggered. I pass the function in to the component like this:

```
<RichTextEditor handleReturn={this.handleReturn} value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.onChange}/>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE: I ended up implementing the underlying `draft.js` library (https://draftjs.org/) directly instead. Was a pretty smooth process and it resolved this issue, by bypassing the use of `react-rte`. So would recommend switching if you have the possibility.

Answer (score -2):

This can help, kinda long for just resetting an input, but it works

```js
handleReturn = () => {
  let {editorState} = this.state;
  let contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const firstBlock = contentState.getFirstBlock();
  const lastBlock = contentState.getLastBlock();
  const allSelected = new SelectionState({
    anchorKey: firstBlock.getKey(),
    anchorOffset: 0,
    focusKey: lastBlock.getKey(),
    focusOffset: lastBlock.getLength(),
    hasFocus: true
  });
  contentState = Modifier.removeRange(contentState, allSelected, 'backward');
  editorState = EditorState.push(editorState, contentState, 'remove-range');
  editorState = EditorState.forceSelection(contentState, contentState.getSelectionAfter());
  this.setState({editorState});
```